# 3D Game using 2D Ortographic camera

Tags: 3d, unity-game-engine

I'm scaling enemy of 800 polygons while moving them throw space and animating them while using an orthographic camera and cheap shaders ... but i'm having really bad problems with performance (super high drawcalls , low framerate) for Iphone 3G , 4 ,4S.

When i disable the scaling , performance goes very well .

Then my question is , Are there any other ways to use an ortographic camera or simulating an ortographic camera with a good performance without scaling the elements in the game?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by using an orthographic camera? It's almost never useful.

Comment: @DanHulme That's not true... Any 2D or isometric game requires an orthographic camera. They're also appropriate for UI, which most games need.

Comment: @DanHulme ask my boss . I'm trying to convince them to not try to use that bad thing :( .

Comment: @RhysvanderWaerden Yes, that's fair enough. From the mention of an 800 poly enemy in the question, I just assumed it's not about 2D UI or anything like that. Maybe "almost never" was a bit too strong.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to use a orthographic camera without scaling.

In the Inspector tab of the camera you will see three options: size, near and far clipping. 
Adjust these values to your desired scene size and you will be fine. :)